# How to parse parameters from text?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text that looks like:

```
ENGINE = CollapsingMergeTree (
    first_param
    ,(
        second_a
        ,second_b, second_c,
        ,second d), third, fourth)
```

Engine can be different (instead of CollapsingMergeTree, there can be different word, ReplacingMergeTree, SummingMergeTree...) but the text is always in format ENGINE = word (). Around "=" sign, can be space, but it is not mandatory.
Inside parenthesis are several parameters usually a single word and comma, but some parameters are in parenthesis like second in the example above.
Line breaks could be anywhere. Line can end with comma, parenthesis or anything else.

I need to extract n parameters (I don't know how many in advance). In example above, there are 4 parameters:

1. first = first_param
2. second = (second_a, second_b, second_c, second_d) [extract with parenthesis]
3. third = third
4. fourth = fourth

How to do that with python (regex or anything else)?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use a proper parser (and so look up how to hand-roll a parser for a simple language) for whatever language that is, but since what little you show here looks Python-compatible you could just parse it as if it were Python using the `ast` module (from the standard library) and then manipulate the result.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a regex solution for your problem. I tried to keep the regex pattern as 'generic' as I could, because I don't know if there will always be newlines and whitespace in your text, which means the pattern selects a lot of whitespace, which is then removed afterwards.

```
#Import the module for regular expressions
import re

#Text to search. I CORRECTED IT A BIT AS YOUR EXAMPLE SAID second d AND second_c WAS FOLLOWED BY TWO COMMAS. I am assuming those were typos.
text = '''ENGINE = CollapsingMergeTree (
    first_param
    ,(
        second_a
        ,second_b, second_c
        ,second_d), third, fourth)'''

#Regex search pattern. re.S means . which represents ANY character, includes \n (newlines)
pattern = re.compile('ENGINE = CollapsingMergeTree \((.*?),\((.*?)\),(.*?), (.*?)\)', re.S) #ENGINE = CollapsingMergeTree \((.*?),\((.*?)\), (.*?), (.*?)\)

#Apply the pattern to the text and save the results in variable 'result'. result[0] would return whole text.
#The items you want are sub-expressions which are enclosed in parentheses () and can be accessed by using result[1] and above
result = re.match(pattern, text)

#result[1] will get everything after theparenteses after CollapsingMergeTree until it reaches a , (comma), but with whitespace and newlines. re.sub is used to replace all whitespace, including newlines, with nothing
first = re.sub('\s', '', result[1])

#result[2] will get second a-d, but with whitespace and newlines. re.sub is used to replace all whitespace, including newlines, with nothing
second = re.sub('\s', '', result[2])

third = re.sub('\s', '', result[3])

fourth = re.sub('\s', '', result[4])

print(first)
print(second)
print(third)
print(fourth)
```

OUTPUT:

```
first_param
second_a,second_b,second_c,second_d
third
fourth
```

Regex explanation:
\ = Escapes a control character, which is a character regex would interpret to mean something special. More [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm).

\( = Escape parentheses

() = Mark the expression in the parentheses as a sub-group. See result[1] and so on.

. = Matches any character (including newline, because of re.S)

* = Matches 0 or more occurrences of preceding expression.

? = Matches 0 or 1 occurrence of preceding expression.

NOTE: *? combined is called a nongreedy repetition, meaning the preceding expression is only matched once, instead of over and over again.

I am no expert, but I hope I got the explanations right.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I forgot to say that instead of CollapsingMergeTree, there could be 10 different words (ReplacingMergeTree, SummingMergeTree), but it is always in format ENGINE = *MergeTree(param1, param2, ..., paramN). Engine and equal sign can be separated by space but it is not mandatory.
Furthermore, parameters should stay as they are, so second parameter should be "(second_a,second_b,second_c,second_d)" instead of "second_a,second_b,second_c,second_d".
Number of parameters also varies.

Comment: Lets, say that I can extract everything between first and last parenthesis, so I should extract various number of  parameters and some of them can be in parenthesis.

Comment: Try this regex pattern. It does not look for a specific word after ENGINE = and leaves the parentheses around second_ a-d.
`'ENGINE =.*?\((.*?),(.*?\)),(.*?), (.*?)\)'`

Comment: It works if text is in single line and if I know how many parameters will be between parenthesis. I am looking for modular solution that will extract parameters divided by commas and respect parenthesis.

Comment: At this point I recommend that you have a look at how to do a regex search yourself if you want to go down that route as you know the script you are using better than anybody. I hope I was able to give you some useful tools for along the way.

Comment: Yes you did MondQ. Thank you very much.